# Icons within the community menu are oddly misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, favicon, stack-exchange-button

[image: Bug]

This is my screenshot of this **bug**.
But there are more than 100 bugged images (on ***[Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)***, *etc...*).
And some images are ***not*** bugged.

Comment: Could just be a change to the sprite sheet without a corresponding change to the CSS.

Comment: Already reported on the main Meta: [Favicon sprites are offset in site list dropdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381137/165261)

Comment: @HereticMonkey, it's too a  bug, but with graphics(not in code)

Comment: Never said it wasn't a bug... Just speculated on the source of the problem, which would indeed be with the "graphics" (a sprite sheet is an image file containing all of the logos for the sites; CSS is needed to position that image correctly so that the correct logo is displayed; see [this article for more](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)).

Comment: Workaround: Just use dark mode ;) (it works in dark mode, since that uses a different sprite sheet)

Comment: Or light mode at 150% zoom, which also uses a different sprite sheet.

Answer (score 4):

[Reported on the global Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381137), confirmed to be related to the roll-out of new themes for certain Stack Exchange network sites and an issue with the stylesheet defining the icons as being 1 px wider than they should have been (but only for light themes; dark theme was unaffected), and [noted as fixed by developer Felippe Rangel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381143).

Comment: I don't like it.

Comment: What do you mean you don't like it? What don't you like?